# Having a hard time getting sentiment analysis bot to calibrate bet probabilities well

Tags: machine-learning

Training a language model for taking bets in the stock market based on news. For each news release I have three categories for each stock: long bet, short bet, or neither. The NN outputs probabilities for each category.

I'm having a surprisingly hard time getting a good calibration for the probabilities. If I use **EV** as the loss function, there's no reason to ever not take a bet, no matter how small your opinion over the signal is, because you can set

P(long) = 0.5, P(short) = 0.5

for a very slightly positive EV (because once in a while the price hits both hypothetical profit takers without hitting the stop losses).

On the other hand I use **expected utility** as the loss, with utility = log(profit). This way a bet with EV close to 0 and positive risk has negative expected utility. However, as I tweak the size of the bet, the NN goes straight from ignoring the risk to never betting with very slight changes in bet size.

I could hunt for the perfect value, but I don't like how fragile results are to a hyperparameter choice.

How do I get the model to only bet when it's confident?